# RegexBuilder DSL to verify a string has a special character

Tags: swift, regex

I am trying to replace legacy code with new API. Need to verify that a string has 1, or more, special character. The list with special characters is not known at compile time, it comes from a service.

This is not working for me.

```swift
import UIKit
import RegexBuilder

var greeting = "Hello, playground_;! +-$"

let specialCharacterPattern = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};\':\",.<>?]/

let specialRegex = Regex {
    Capture {
        ChoiceOf {
            "1"
            "@"
            "#"
        }
    }
    specialCharacterPattern
    
    /\+|-/
}

if greeting.contains(specialRegex) {
    print("Yes")
} else {
    print("No")
}
```

Is there an equivalent for `ForEach` to iterate through possible choices to capture?

Comment: How about just use ```let result = greeting.contains {
    /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};\':\",.<>?]/
   }

   print(result)```